# Know who fired the event "focusout"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `focusout` in a code and I need to know which element was clicked to fire the `focusout` because I need to execute a specific function if a specific element was responsible in firing `focusout`

I tried to use `stopPropagation` but it dosen't work

```
  $('#buscar_menu .select2-search__field').focusout(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    /*if(e.target.classList[0] == "search_field"){
        console.log("eureca");

    }else{
                    console.log("not eureca");
            }*/
});
```

Comment: I think you need to rethink what you're trying to do. You can lose focus from an element in more ways than clicking something.

Comment: problem is focusout is not really an event you can cancel.

Comment: Why not use the `click` event handler and have if statements in that?

Comment: You could try to find the element that received `focusin`, but it's not totally clear to in which order those events would occur. Also you can cause `focusout` without actually having any other element receive `focusin` (e.g. clicking outside the browser window).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `jQuery` you can add the data attribute with a custom property name like `data-responsible-element`; this can be retrieved using `jQuery's` `data()` method to retrieve the element that lost focus.

In short:
Set `data-{custom-property}="{some-value}"` in an element and after the event has been triggered retrieve `{some-value}` from `data-{custom-property}` using `data()` method.

With this method you can set `{some-value}` to be an `unique identifier` for **that** element which would enable you to `query` the element.

```js
$('.focusable').focusout(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  var element_that_lost_focus = $(this).data('responsible-element');
  
  console.log(element_that_lost_focus + ' just lost focus!? D:');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="focusable" placeholder="Juan" data-responsible-element="Juan" />
<input class="focusable" placeholder="Carlos" data-responsible-element="Carlos" />
<input class="focusable" placeholder="Martín" data-responsible-element="Martín" />
<input class="focusable" placeholder="John Doe" data-responsible-element="John Doe" />
```